# Request/Reply initiated by the server using SignalR

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, signalr

I have the following scenario:

- Many clients (WinForm/WPF, not browsers) connect to a SignalR server (either Hub or PersistedConnection)
- Server keeps a list of the connected clients
- At some point, based on some background processes, the server requires information from one of the clients

As far as I know, SignalR support returning values from server methods called by the client, but not for client methods called by the server.

For that, I've implemented a simple mechanism:

1. Server finds the relevant client (via Connection Id)
2. Server generates a unique Id (Guid), and keeps a TaskCompletionSource with that Id
3. Server calls the relevant client, and sends the unique Id
4. Server awaits on the TaskCompletionSource
5. Client retrieve the information, and send it back (using a regular server method call), along with the unique Id
6. Server (on a different thread) finds the correct TaskCompletionSource based on the unique Id, and calls SetResult()
7. The await on the TaskCompletionSource completes, and Server has the result

This feels like forcing SignalR to perform things it was not meant to do.

Does anyone know if this can be better implemented/support by SignalR?

Does anyone has a better suggestion for this scenario?

**Notes:**

- I considered using Sockets/WebSockets, but they seem a very low-level for my need, and don't provide a request-response paradigm
- WCF Full Duplex works, but requires opening a port on the client side, as well as requiring the client to have a public IP address.
- I'm expecting many clients, installed on my end-users' computers, so internet latency, firewalls, security, etc. are all a consideration (which is why I prefer using SignalR, which seems to avoid most of these issues)

Comment: Your current mechanism sounds good. I would just add a `SetCanceled` call if the client disconnects, because [you always want to complete your tasks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/02/10218999.aspx).

Comment: @SaguiItay: How did you go about it in the end?